# How do I mock a Session in Ratpack with RequestFixture?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, ratpack

What I'm trying to do is test an authentication handler, but my problem boils down to having no `Session` instance in the registry.

An example test:

```
package whatever

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import ratpack.groovy.handling.GroovyChainAction
import ratpack.groovy.test.handling.GroovyRequestFixture
import ratpack.http.Status
import ratpack.session.Session
import spock.lang.Specification

class SessionChainTest extends Specification {
    GroovyChainAction sessionChain = new GroovyChainAction() {
        @Override
        @CompileStatic
        void execute() throws Exception {
            get('foo') {
                Session s = get Session
                // Stuff using session here
            }
        }
    }

    def "should get session"() {
        given:
        def result = GroovyRequestFixture.handle(sessionChain) {
            uri 'foo'
            method 'GET'
        }

        expect:
        result.status == Status.OK

        // If the server threw, rethrow that
        Throwable t = result.exception(Throwable)
        if (t) throw t // <<< Throws NotInRegistryException because no Session in registry
    }

}
```

(The extra rethrow is in there to allow us to see the exception thrown within the ratpack test, because by default it is caught and stashed in the result.)

I know that in principle I could create a Session instance and add it to the registry with a `registry { add <Session instance> }` block, but I've delved into the Ratpack code, and creating a Session object requires getting a lot of disparate other components and passing them to `SessionModule#sessionAdaptor` (or the `DefaultSession` constructor). I can't find any examples of that being done, it appears this call is handled by Guice dependency-injection magic I can't unpick.

The usual way to do it in an application is to use a `bind { module SessionModule }` block but this isn't accessible from the context of `RequestFixture#execute`.

As sessions are bread and butter for any web application, my hunch is that this may be an easily solved problem, I just haven't found the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `Registry` through `GroovyRequestFixture.handle(handler, closure)` method call and you can e.g. register mocked `Session` object:

```
GroovyRequestFixture.handle(sessionChain) {
    uri 'foo'
    method 'GET'
    registry { r ->
        r.add(Session, session)
    }
}
```

Take a look at following example:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import ratpack.exec.Promise
import ratpack.groovy.handling.GroovyChainAction
import ratpack.groovy.test.handling.GroovyRequestFixture
import ratpack.http.Status
import ratpack.jackson.internal.DefaultJsonRender
import ratpack.session.Session
import spock.lang.Specification

import static ratpack.jackson.Jackson.json

class SessionChainTest extends Specification {

    Session session = Mock(Session) {
        get('test') >> Promise.value(Optional.of('Lorem ipsum'))
    }

    GroovyChainAction sessionChain = new GroovyChainAction() {
        @Override
        @CompileStatic
        void execute() throws Exception {
            get('foo') {
                Session s = get Session

                s.get('test').map { Optional<String> o ->
                    o.orElse(null)
                }.flatMap { value ->
                    Promise.value(value)
                }.then {
                    render(json([message: it]))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def "should get session"() {
        given:
        def result = GroovyRequestFixture.handle(sessionChain) {
            uri 'foo'
            method 'GET'
            registry { r ->
                r.add(Session, session)
            }
        }

        expect:
        result.status == Status.OK

        and:
        result.rendered(DefaultJsonRender).object == [message: 'Lorem ipsum']

    }
}
```

In this test I mock `Session` object for key `test` to store `Lorem ipsum` text. When running this test, both assertions pass.

#### Alternative approach: registering `Guice.registry()`

If you don't want to use mocked `Session` object you can try replacing default Ratpack's `Registry` with a Guice registry object. Firstly, initialize a function that creates Guice registry and add `SessionModule` via bindings:

```
static Function<Registry, Registry> guiceRegistry = Guice.registry { bindings ->
    bindings.module(new SessionModule())
}
```

Next inside `execute()` method of `GroovyChainAction` you can replace the default registry by calling:

```
register(guiceRegistry.apply(registry))
```

No mocks anymore, but in this case you can't access `Session` object outside request scope, so you wont be able to add anything to the session in preparation stage of your test. Below you can find full example:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import ratpack.exec.Promise
import ratpack.func.Function
import ratpack.groovy.handling.GroovyChainAction
import ratpack.groovy.test.handling.GroovyRequestFixture
import ratpack.guice.Guice
import ratpack.http.Status
import ratpack.jackson.internal.DefaultJsonRender
import ratpack.registry.Registry
import ratpack.session.Session
import ratpack.session.SessionModule
import spock.lang.Specification

import static ratpack.jackson.Jackson.json

class SessionChainTest extends Specification {

    static Function<Registry, Registry> guiceRegistry = Guice.registry { bindings ->
        bindings.module(new SessionModule())
    }

    GroovyChainAction sessionChain = new GroovyChainAction() {
        @Override
        @CompileStatic
        void execute() throws Exception {
            register(guiceRegistry.apply(registry))

            get('foo') {
                Session s = get Session

                s.get('test').map { Optional<String> o ->
                    o.orElse(null)
                }.flatMap { value ->
                    Promise.value(value)
                }.then {
                    render(json([message: it]))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def "should get session"() {
        given:
        def result = GroovyRequestFixture.handle(sessionChain) {
            uri 'foo'
            method 'GET'
        }

        expect:
        result.status == Status.OK

        and:
        result.rendered(DefaultJsonRender).object == [message: null]

    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I still have a snag however, and perhaps I shouldn't have used the word "Mock". I'm testing against `RatpackPac4j.requireAuth(HeaderClient)` which does stuff internally with the session, so I need something which behaves like a real `Session` which can interact with that in ways I don't know or care about.  A Mock() can't provide the appropriate behaviour.

Comment: @wu-lee In this case you may try replacing the default Ratpack registry object with the one created by `Guice.registry { bindings -> }` function. Take a look at updated example.

Comment: I think this gets me past the registry issue and on to yet new ones with `RatpackPac4j`...