# Given a Ratpack RequestFixture test, how can I have the fixture invoke Request#beforeSend?

Tags: java, groovy, ratpack, www-authenticate

This question is in the context of a Ratpack `RequestFixture` Spock test, for a Ratpack chain authenticating with `RatpackPac4j#requireAuth`, and employing a workaround for the missing `WWW-Authenticate` header (as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926500/is-there-a-way-to-work-around-ratpackpac4jrequireauth-not-setting-the-www-authe))

The problem I have is, I find that `#beforeSend` appears to be uncalled when the response is obtained from `GroovyRequestFixture#handle` (a wrapper for `RequestFixture#handle`). The work-around depends on this to work, so I can't test it.  Is there a way to get `#beforeSend` called on the response represented by the `HandlingResult` returned?

For example, this test case fails with the assertion that the `WWW-Authenticate` header is present, even though the code this is adapted from inserts the header correctly when called in the actual application.  The chain under test is `testChain`, skip to the end for the failing assertion:

```
package whatever

import com.google.inject.Module
import groovy.transform.Canonical
import groovy.transform.CompileDynamic
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.pac4j.core.profile.jwt.JwtClaims
import org.pac4j.http.client.direct.HeaderClient
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.encryption.EncryptionConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.encryption.SecretEncryptionConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.signature.SecretSignatureConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.signature.SignatureConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.credentials.authenticator.JwtAuthenticator
import org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtGenerator
import org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtProfile
import ratpack.groovy.handling.GroovyChainAction
import ratpack.groovy.test.handling.GroovyRequestFixture
import ratpack.guice.Guice
import ratpack.http.Response
import ratpack.http.Status
import ratpack.jackson.Jackson
import ratpack.pac4j.RatpackPac4j
import ratpack.registry.Registry
import ratpack.session.SessionModule
import ratpack.test.handling.HandlerExceptionNotThrownException
import ratpack.test.handling.HandlingResult
import spock.lang.Specification

@CompileStatic
class AuthenticatorTest extends Specification {
    static byte[] salt = new byte[32] // dummy salt

    static SignatureConfiguration signatureConfiguration = new SecretSignatureConfiguration(salt)
    static EncryptionConfiguration encryptionConfiguration = new SecretEncryptionConfiguration(salt)
    static JwtAuthenticator authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(signatureConfiguration, encryptionConfiguration)
    static JwtGenerator generator = new JwtGenerator(signatureConfiguration, encryptionConfiguration)
    static HeaderClient headerClient = new HeaderClient("Authorization", "bearer ", authenticator)

    /** A stripped down user class */
    @Canonical
    static class User {
        final String id
    }

    /** A stripped down user registry class */
    @Canonical
    static class UserRegistry {
        private final Map<String, String> users = [
            'joebloggs': 'sekret'
        ]

        User authenticate(String id, String password) {
            if (password != null && users[id] == password)
               return new User(id)
            return null
        }
    }

    /** Generates a JWT token for a given user
     *
     * @param userId - the name of the user
     * @return A JWT token encoded as a string
     */
    static String generateToken(String userId) {
        JwtProfile profile = new JwtProfile()
        profile.id = userId
        profile.addAttribute(JwtClaims.ISSUED_AT, new Date())
        String token = generator.generate(profile)
        token
    }

    static void trapExceptions(HandlingResult result) {
        try {
            Throwable t = result.exception(Throwable)
            throw t
        }
        catch (HandlerExceptionNotThrownException ignored) {
        }
    }

    /** Composes a new registry binding the module class passed
     * as per SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814817/how-do-i-mock-a-session-in-ratpack-with-requestfixture
     */
    static Registry addModule(Registry registry, Class<? extends Module> module) {
        Guice.registry { it.module(module) }.apply(registry)
    }

    GroovyChainAction testChain = new GroovyChainAction() {
        @Override
        @CompileDynamic
        void execute() throws Exception {

            register addModule(registry, SessionModule)

            all RatpackPac4j.authenticator(headerClient)

            all {
                /*
                 * This is a workaround for an issue in RatpackPac4j v2.0.0, which doesn't
                 * add the WWW-Authenticate header by itself.
                 *
                 * See https://github.com/pac4j/ratpack-pac4j/issues/3
                 *
                 * This handler needs to be ahead of any potential causes of 401 statuses
                 */
                response.beforeSend { Response response ->
                    if (response.status.code == 401) {
                        response.headers.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'bearer realm="authenticated api"')
                    }
                }
                next()
            }

            post('login') { UserRegistry users ->
                parse(Jackson.fromJson(Map)).then { Map data ->
                    // Validate the credentials
                    String id = data.user
                    String password = data.password
                    User user = users.authenticate(id, password)
                    if (user == null) {
                        clientError(401) // Bad authentication credentials
                    } else {
                        response.contentType('text/plain')

                        // Authenticates ok. Issue a JWT token to the client which embeds (signed, encrypted)
                        // certain standardised metadata of our choice that the JWT validation will use.
                        String token = generateToken(user.id)
                        render token
                    }
                }
            }

            get('unprotected') {
                render "hello"
            }

            // All subsequent paths require authentication
            all RatpackPac4j.requireAuth(HeaderClient)

            get('protected') {
                render "hello"
            }

            notFound()
        }
    }

    @CompileDynamic
    def "should be denied protected path, unauthorised..."() {
        given:
        def result = GroovyRequestFixture.handle(testChain) {
            uri 'protected'
            method 'GET'
        }

        expect:
        result.status == Status.of(401) // Unauthorized


        // THIS FAILS BECAUSE Response#beforeSend WASN'T INVOKED BY GroovyRequestFixture
        result.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] == 'bearer realm="authenticated api"'

        // If the server threw, rethrow that
        trapExceptions(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best answer so far... or more strictly, a workaround to sidestep the limitations of `RequestFixture`, is: don't use `RequestFixture`. Use [`GroovyEmbeddedApp`](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/groovy/test/embed/GroovyEmbeddedApp.html)

(Credit to [Dan Hyun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4487193/dan-hyun) on the Ratpack slack channel)

> RequestFixture is only meant to check handler behavior, it doesn't do a lot of 
>   things - it won't serialize responses. `EmbeddedApp` is probably the way to go
>   for most testing. You'd care more about overall interaction rather than how an
>   individual handler does a thing, unless it was a highly reused component or is 
>   middleware that is used by other apps

An modified version of the example above follows, I've marked the modified sections in the comments:

```
package whatever

import com.google.inject.Module
import groovy.transform.Canonical
import groovy.transform.CompileDynamic
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.pac4j.core.profile.jwt.JwtClaims
import org.pac4j.http.client.direct.HeaderClient
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.encryption.EncryptionConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.encryption.SecretEncryptionConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.signature.SecretSignatureConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.config.signature.SignatureConfiguration
import org.pac4j.jwt.credentials.authenticator.JwtAuthenticator
import org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtGenerator
import org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtProfile
import ratpack.groovy.test.embed.GroovyEmbeddedApp
import ratpack.guice.Guice
import ratpack.http.Response
import ratpack.http.Status
import ratpack.http.client.ReceivedResponse
import ratpack.jackson.Jackson
import ratpack.pac4j.RatpackPac4j
import ratpack.registry.Registry
import ratpack.session.SessionModule
import ratpack.test.handling.HandlerExceptionNotThrownException
import ratpack.test.handling.HandlingResult
import ratpack.test.http.TestHttpClient
import spock.lang.Specification

@CompileStatic
class TempTest extends Specification {
    static byte[] salt = new byte[32] // dummy salt

    static SignatureConfiguration signatureConfiguration = new SecretSignatureConfiguration(salt)
    static EncryptionConfiguration encryptionConfiguration = new SecretEncryptionConfiguration(salt)
    static JwtAuthenticator authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(signatureConfiguration, encryptionConfiguration)
    static JwtGenerator generator = new JwtGenerator(signatureConfiguration, encryptionConfiguration)
    static HeaderClient headerClient = new HeaderClient("Authorization", "bearer ", authenticator)

    /** A stripped down user class */
    @Canonical
    static class User {
        final String id
    }

    /** A stripped down user registry class */
    @Canonical
    static class UserRegistry {
        private final Map<String, String> users = [
            'joebloggs': 'sekret'
        ]

        User authenticate(String id, String password) {
            if (password != null && users[id] == password)
                return new User(id)
            return null
        }
    }

    /** Generates a JWT token for a given user
     *
     * @param userId - the name of the user
     * @return A JWT token encoded as a string
     */
    static String generateToken(String userId) {
        JwtProfile profile = new JwtProfile()
        profile.id = userId
        profile.addAttribute(JwtClaims.ISSUED_AT, new Date())
        String token = generator.generate(profile)
        token
    }

    static void trapExceptions(HandlingResult result) {
        try {
            Throwable t = result.exception(Throwable)
            throw t
        }
        catch (HandlerExceptionNotThrownException ignored) {
        }
    }

    /** Composes a new registry binding the module class passed
     * as per SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814817/how-do-i-mock-a-session-in-ratpack-with-requestfixture
     */
    static Registry addModule(Registry registry, Class<? extends Module> module) {
        Guice.registry { it.module(module) }.apply(registry)
    }

    /*** USE GroovyEmbeddedApp HERE INSTEAD OF GroovyResponseFixture ***/
    GroovyEmbeddedApp testApp = GroovyEmbeddedApp.ratpack {
        bindings {
            module SessionModule
        }

        handlers {
            all RatpackPac4j.authenticator(headerClient)

            all {
                /*
                 * This is a workaround for an issue in RatpackPac4j v2.0.0, which doesn't
                 * add the WWW-Authenticate header by itself.
                 *
                 * See https://github.com/pac4j/ratpack-pac4j/issues/3
                 *
                 * This handler needs to be ahead of any potential causes of 401 statuses
                 */
                response.beforeSend { Response response ->
                    if (response.status.code == 401) {
                        response.headers.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'bearer realm="authenticated api"')
                    }
                }
                next()
            }

            post('login') { UserRegistry users ->
                parse(Jackson.fromJson(Map)).then { Map data ->
                    // Validate the credentials
                    String id = data.user
                    String password = data.password
                    User user = users.authenticate(id, password)
                    if (user == null) {
                        clientError(401) // Bad authentication credentials
                    } else {
                        response.contentType('text/plain')

                        // Authenticates ok. Issue a JWT token to the client which embeds (signed, encrypted)
                        // certain standardised metadata of our choice that the JWT validation will use.
                        String token = generateToken(user.id)
                        render token
                    }
                }
            }

            get('unprotected') {
                render "hello"
            }

            // All subsequent paths require authentication
            all RatpackPac4j.requireAuth(HeaderClient)

            get('protected') {
                render "hello"
            }

            notFound()
        }
    }


    /*** THIS NOW ALTERED TO USE testApp ***/
    @CompileDynamic
    def "should be denied protected path, unauthorised..."() {
        given:
        TestHttpClient client = testApp.httpClient
        ReceivedResponse response = client.get('protected')

        expect:
        response.status == Status.of(401) // Unauthorized
        response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] == 'bearer realm="authenticated api"'
    }
}
```